# How can i remove title requirement for content type

Tags: 7, nodes

For example i have content type `article` i need to remove requirement for title, right now its a `Node module element` and i can not edit it. I found module [title](http://drupal.org/project/title) but when i installed id and tried to change title, my site crashed.

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Should i remove title on content type edit page and replace it with editable field?

*UPDATE:*

Some of you maybe do not understand me right). So i have content type `Answer` and this c.type has two fields `title` and `body`. When someone want to `answer` atm he needs to fill `title` field every time he wants to answer, but i need to give user a choice to just fill only `body` field OR `body` and `title` if user want to fill the `title`. The title field should be displayed on node edit every time!

So only way i see viable is to create new `field` and  hide `title` with automatic-node-title module...

Comment: Why do you want to remove the requirement? Do you just need to hide the title or remove it completely?

Comment: i have a content type answer, so if user want to answer he can not add a titl, i dont need to remove it

Comment: What @jan said, i'd recommend auto-nodetitle module then as well...

Comment: @neok, I agree with jan. You can use [Auto Node title](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and you can hide the title in the node view page using template override or `display:none` from css.

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' think you can entirely remove the title from the nodes but you may hide it and automatically populate it, as is below:

[Auto node titles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and [Title override](http://drupal.org/project/title_override)

I have used the first one before.

Comment: i dont need to hide it, just need to remove requirement, but gonna check those modules

Comment: I think the title field in the node table schema is not allowed to accept null values, which would be a possibilty if you'd remove the requirement. So hiding the title and use it just in the backend would be the way to go...

Comment: i updated my question, you can see what i am actually need, i believe this is not the goal i am looking for.

Comment: Your requirement is not common. As what @Volker pointed out it cannot accept null values. Perhaps you can pull this off using a custom module, similar to auto node title but with a little extra -- toggles title to hide/unhide as required.

Comment: ok, this module has helped me.

Comment: Did you manage to hide/unhide the title field on demand? It might help us in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

How to hide or remove title for content type.

1 Install [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel)

2 Install [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)

**For Content Type News** go to

**D7** admin/structure/types/manage/news/auto_label

**D8/9** admin/structure/types/manage/news/auto-label

Then select an option that fit your solution, in my case I selected:
**Automatically generate the label and hide the label field**

In the **Pattern for the label** enter field token to replace the **Title**.

in my case I entered `[node:filed_slogan]`.

[image]